# Add text to configurable products on category page

Tags: magento, configurable-product

Since I'm using Magento 1.9.1 with a custom theme, I'm not able to use the built in functionality for swatches.

Still, I would like to show that a product is available in multiple colors. This should obviously only be the case for configurable products. It only has to show the text "More colors".

It could look something like this:

```
<img src="blanket.png">
<span>More colors</span>
<span>€99,99</span>
```

I would have posted an image, but my reputation is too low :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if I understand well what you need, but if you want to display the message "More Colors" on the grid of the category of products, you must edit the list file, which is in

*app / design / frontend / your-theme / yout-theme / template / catalog / product / list.phtml*

You must add something like this

```
      <?php 
       if ($_product->isConfigurable()) { 
       //content configurable
       echo '<span>More Colors</span>';
       } else {
       // content if not configurable
       }
       ?>
```

Good Luck!